# Load many feather files in a folder into dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, feather

With a folder with many `.feather` files, I would like to load all of them into dask in python.

So far, I have tried the following sourced from a similar question on GitHub https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1277

```
files = [...]
dfs = [dask.delayed(feather.read_dataframe)(f) for f in files]
df = dd.concat(dfs)
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error  `TypeError: Truth of Delayed objects is not supported` which is mentioned there, but a workaround is not clear.

Is it possible to do the above in dask?

Comment: You need to turn your delayed object into an actual dataframe. Try `dd.from_delayed()`.

Comment: ^ this should be made into an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `concat`, which operates on dataframes, you want to use [`from_delayed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed), which turns a list of delayed objects, each of which represents a dataframe, into a single logical dataframe

```
dfs = [dask.delayed(feather.read_dataframe)(f) for f in files]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

If possible, you should also supply the `meta=` (a zero-length dataframe, describing the columns, index and dtypes) and `divisions=` (the boundary values of the index along the partitions) kwargs.