# Pandas - Serialize Large DataFrame

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, data-science

I would like to serialize my DataFrame. The DataFrame uses 10.1 GB of memory and has 59 million entries.

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 59181090 entries, 0 to 59181089
Data columns (total 22 columns):
(...)
dtypes: float64(1), int64(9), object(12)
memory usage: 10.1+ GB
```

When I serialize the DataFrame with feather and then re-import the serialized DataFrame, it appears to corrupt the DataFrame.

```
df.("raw_df.feather")

unserialized_df = pd.read_feather("raw_df.feather")

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22909623 entries, 0 to 22909622
Data columns (total 22 columns):
(...)
dtypes: float64(2), int64(8), object(12)
memory usage: 3.8+ GB
```

It also introduces a small number of NaN values where there were none before.

What's the best way to serialize a large DataFrame?

I'm using an ml.m4.10xlarge AWS instance with SageMaker with a JupyterLab interface. I have 30GB of storage available with 4GB used so I should be affected by a storage limitation.

I have 160GiB of main memory so I should not have an issue with handling the whole DataFrame.

I am using Pandas 0.24.2 with Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) [GCC 7.2.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
unserialized_df = dd.read_feather("raw_df.feather").compute()
```

Source: [Load many feather files in a folder into dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403908/load-many-feather-files-in-a-folder-into-dask)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an efficient binary format that serializes tabular data, called [BinTableFile](https://pypi.org/project/bintablefile/) [Github
source code](https://github.com/eSAMTrade/bintablefile).
It indexes the data in the file and is efficient on reading from the middle of the file by the integer index, and is written in Cython for speed efficiency.