# Loading feather files from s3 with dask delayed

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-delayed, feather

I have an s3 folder with multiple `.feather` files, I would like to load these into `dask` using python as described here: [Load many feather files in a folder into dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403908/load-many-feather-files-in-a-folder-into-dask). I have tried two ways both give me different errors:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask 

ftr_filenames = [
    's3://my-bucket/my-dir/file_1.ftr', 
    's3://my-bucket/my-dir/file_2.ftr', 
     .
     .
     .
    's3://my-bucket/my-dir/file_30.ftr'
]
delayed_files = dask.bytes.open_files(ftr_filenames, 'rb')

# ---------------------------option 1 --------------------------------
dfs = [dask.delayed(pd.read_feather)(f) for f in delayed_files]
# ---------------------------option 2 --------------------------------
dfs = [dask.delayed(feather.read_dataframe)(f) for f in delayed_files]
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(dfs)

# -------------------------- error 1 ------------------------------
# 'S3File' object has no attribute '__fspath__'
# -------------------------- error 2 ------------------------------
# Cannot convert OpenFile to pyarrow.lib.NativeFile
```

is there another way to read these files from s3 ?, the main purpose here is to circumvent memory issues caused by `pd.concat`.